# What are the downsides and upsides of having all business logic inside App_Code folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, .net-4.0

Scenario:
Company X has created a large ASP.NET application. Many other companies create sub-applications. Let's assume ~10 companies and a total of ~100 sub-applications.

There is an *interesting* requirement for the sub-applications. No DLLs can be deployed to the production server. Only .ascx/.ascx.cs/.cs files and .css/.js/image files can be deployed.

Sub-application I work on was developed as Web Application, however not deploying DLLs and using CodeFile makes it similar to Web Site.

Sub-applications are deployed like this:

1. .ascx and .ascx.cs files go to:

   ```
   inetpub\wwwroot\LargeSystem\layouts\CompanyName\ApplicationName\
   ```
2. .cs files go to App_Code folder:

   ```
   LargeSystem\App_Code\CompanyName\ApplicationName\
   ```

This leads to a directory structure similar to this in the App_Code folder.

```
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company1\Application1
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company1\Application2
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company1\Application3
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company2\Application4
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company2\Application5
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company3\Application6
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company3\Application7
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company3\Application8
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company3\Application9
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company3\Application10
LargeSystem\App_Code\Company4\Application11
... and the list goes on.
```

All .cs classes inside App_Code are compiled into App_Code.dll. DLL name has a random string attached to it every time it is recompiled.

I'm failing to see any upsides to this approach. I have not found any resource which recommends storing all business logic inside App_Code. But it can be done, and there must be some upsides for this approach, if it's an actual requirement. Avoiding dependency issues is the only reason I've heard so far from company X.

Problems I see with this approach:

1. App_Code compilation will take a long time. I don't know if there are limitations to how large the App_Code.dll or how long the compilation time can be.
2. Compilation error in any of the .cs files leads to the App_Code.dll not being compiled. I don't see a way around this.
3. Code of unrelated applications stored in one DLL.

Comment: "[T]here must be some upsides for this approach, if it's an actual requirement" -- I wouldn't be so sure of that :)

Comment: downside - interoperability upside - easier to reference